# Comparing values from part of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 columns in DB2 Table:
`PARID` and `LOC`

`PARID VARCHAR2 (10)` and values are like `1005620001 LOC CHAR(1)`.

Now I have to compare the first digit of `PARID` and `LOC` values. 
How can I get the first digit of the `PARID` in SQL query?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LEFT(PARID, 1)` will return the first digit in the column

Answer (score 1):

If your first digit is always the first character in PARID,

```
LEFT(PARID, 1)
```

will do the job.

If it cannot be guarantee that the first digit is the first character on PARID,

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(PARID, '\d', 1, 1)
```

will do the job, as in the following example:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('  ABC.7.XY', '\d', 1, 1) as FIRST_DIGIT FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

with result:

```
 FIRST_DIGIT
 -----------
 7
```